# VS Code is taking a lot of time to load python modules in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-kernel

When I run for the first time jupyter notebook in vs code takes very long time to connect to kernel and then it takes again a lot of time to load the modules like numpy, pandas, matplotlib etc. For the first problem I tried making a normal .py file so that the interpreter is loaded quickly and that worked. But for the 2nd problem it's still unsolved. Just to mention here a thing that I tried to install python3.10 a few days ago but that had some issues like I was not able to install numpy or other modules then. So I uninstalled python3.10 and also removed it from path variable from settings. And the 2nd problem that I mentioned earlier started after this python3.10 installation-uninstallation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it related to the 2-3 recently released. Could you try to install some early version of `Jupyter` extension?

You can have a look at these pages:

[Slow Kernel startup/restart](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7849)

[Running cells is very slow](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7855)

[image]

Comment: How to install previous versions of jupyter extension?

Comment: @Saqlain Afroz I have updated the answer.